# How do I pass numerical value to a function via input field in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to make a list of products with their prices and quantity fields next to them, and I would like the user to be able to pass a number into the quantity input field, and see the adjusted price, so I came up with something like this:

```
    <li ng-repeat="product in products">
      {{product.price}} - quantity: <input type="text" value="1" ng-model="prodQuantity"> - {{priceTotalProducts(prodQuantity)}}
    </li>
```

Which surely doesn't work. 
Please point me into the right direction!

Comment: can you upload what you have tried on JSFiddle ?

Comment: **What** doesn't work?

Comment: Try using `<input type="number"` it may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ys55zG?p=preview) demonstrating a possible solution.

I changed the markup a bit so that the function calculating the total takes the whole product and the input is bound to the `quantity` property of the `product`:

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="product in products">
            {{product.price}} - quantity: <input type="text" value="1" ng-model="product.quantity" />
         - {{priceTotalProducts(product)}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And here is the controller:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

 $scope.products = [
    { name: "prod1", price: 1.55, quantity: 0 },
    { name: "prod2", price: 2.55, quantity: 0 },
    { name: "prod3", price: 3.55, quantity: 0 },
   ]; 

  $scope.priceTotalProducts = function(product) {

    return product.price * product.quantity;
  }
}
```